# PowerShell: Start a process with unquoted arguments

Tags: powershell

My PowerShell script should start an external executable with specified parameters. I have two strings: The file name, and the arguments. This is what process starting APIs usually want from me. PowerShell however fails at it.

I need to keep the executable and arguments in a separate strings because these are configured elsewhere in my script. This question is just about using these strings to start the process. Also, my script needs to put a common base path in front of the executable.

This is the code:

```
$execFile = "SomeSetup.exe"
$params = "/norestart /verysilent"
& "$basePath\$execFile" $params | Out-Host
# Pipe to the console to wait for it to finish
```

This is the actual result (does not work with this program):

- Process file name: "C:\My\Base path\SomeSetup.exe"
- Process command line: **"/norestart /verysilent"**

This is what I'd expect to have (this would work):

- Process file name: "C:\My\Base path\SomeSetup.exe"
- Process command line: **/norestart /verysilent**

The problem is that the setup recognises the extra quotes and interprets the two arguments as one - and doesn't understand it.

I've seen `Start-Process` but it seems to require each parameter in a string[] which I don't have. Splitting these arguments seems like a complicated shell task, not something I'd do (reliably).

What could I do now? Should I use something like

```
& cmd /c "$execFile $params"
```

But what if $execFile contains spaces which can well happen and usually causes much more headache before you find it.

Comment: Try using single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: Single quotes are the same. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$execFile = "SomeSetup.exe"
$params = "/norestart /verysilent"
Invoke-Expression ($basePath + "\" + $execFile + " " +$params)
```

Comment: According to Microsoft, `Invoke-Expression` is an alias for `&`. And you're missing the quotes around the executable file name.

Comment: It's not missing anything boss, we are creating a string on the fly ;)
Try it with `$execFile = "ipconfig"; $params = "/all"; Invoke-Expression ($execFile + " " +$params)`

Comment: I amended the answer to include your `$basepath`

Comment: @LonelyPixel - Invoke-Expression is not an alias for &.  Invoke-Expression is roughly: write this string out to ps1 file, then run the ps1 file.  & is the invocation operator - it just means - the next value (typically a string or variable) names a command to run.

Comment: Oh cool, German translation is different from English page: http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ee176880.aspx
I'll try this tomorrow.

Comment: This works: `Invoke-Expression ($basePath + "\" + $file + " " + $params + " | Out-Host")`

Comment: Not the prettiest code on earth, but accepted because it's the first and only answer that actually works.

Answer (score 3):

You can put your parameters in an array:

```
$params = "/norestart", "/verysilent"
& $basepath\$execFile $params
```

Answer (score 2):

When you run a legacy command from Powershell it has to convert the powershell variables into a single string that is the legacy command line.

- The program name is always enclosed in quotes.
- Any parameters that contain a space character are enclosed in double
  quotes (this is of course the source of your problem)
- Each element of an array forms a separate argument.

So given:

```
$params = "/norestart /verysilent"
& "$basePath\$execFile" $params
```

Powershell will run the command:

```
"\somepath\SomeSetup.exe" "/norestart /verysilent"
```

The solution is to store separate arguments in an array:

```
$params = "/norestart","/verysilent"
& "$basePath\$execFile" $params
```

will run:

```
"\somepath\SomeSetup.exe" /norestart /verysilent
```

Or if you already have a single string:

```
$params = "/norestart /verysilent"
& "$basePath\$execFile" ($params -split ' ')
```

will work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
& $execFile /norestart /verysilent
```

Bill

Comment: I need to pass the arguments from another configuration section, so this is not configurable enough.

Answer (score -1):

Just use single quotes:

```
$execFile = "SomeSetup.exe"
$params = "/norestart /verysilent"
& "'$basePath\$execFile' $params" | Out-Host
# Pipe to the console to wait for it to finish
```

Also I would use join-path instead of concatenating the two strings:

```
$path = Join-Path $basePath $execFile
& "$path $params" | out-host
```

Comment: Does not work. It tries to find the complete string incl. space and parameters as command and fails.