# Run command line in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, syntax, quoting

I know there are lots of posts regarding this, but nothing worked for me.

I am trying to run this command line in PowerShell:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/ClamWin/bin/clamd.exe --install
```

I have this in PowerShell:

```
&"C:/Program Files (x86)/ClamWin/bin/clamd.exe --install"
```

But all this does is execute `clamd.exe`, ignoring the `--install` parameter

How can I get the full command line to run?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PowerShell: Start a process with unquoted arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22018837/powershell-start-a-process-with-unquoted-arguments)

Comment: `& "C:/Program Files (x86)/ClamWin/bin/clamd.exe" --install` or use apostrophes instead of double quotes.

Comment: @KoryGill: While the linked question is related, this question is distinct in that it is about the fundamentals of the syntax of `&` (whereas the linked question builds on a preexisting basic understanding of it and concerns an advanced aspect that doesn't come into play here).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Josef Z's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404/josefz) comment on the question provides the solution:

```bash
& "C:/Program Files (x86)/ClamWin/bin/clamd.exe" --install # double-quoted exe path
```

or, given that the executable path is a *literal* (contains no variable references or subexpressions), using a [verbatim (single-quoted) string (`'...'`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings):

```bash
& 'C:/Program Files (x86)/ClamWin/bin/clamd.exe' --install # single-quoted exe path
```

As for **why your own solution attempt failed**:

- The call operator, **`&`, expects only a *command name/path* as an argument, not a full *command line***.
  [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression) accepts an entire command line, but that complicates things further and can be a [security risk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/avoid-using-invoke-expression).
- If you want to **store a whole command line in a variable**, for later on-demand execution, **use a *script block* (`{ ... }`)**: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76055264/45375)
- To **construct arguments *programmatically*** for a call to an external program, use [*splatting*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59071135/45375).

As for **why using `&` is the solution**:

- The **need for *quoting*** stands to reason: you need to tell PowerShell that `C:/Program Files (x86)/ClamWin/bin/clamd.exe` is a *single* token (path), despite containing embedded *spaces*.
- The [**need for `&`, the so-called *call operator***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#call-operator-) is due to **PowerShell's two fundamental *parsing modes***:

  - ***argument mode***, which **works like a *traditional shell***, where the first token is a command name, with subsequent tokens representing the arguments, which only require quoting if they contain shell *metacharacters* (chars. with special meaning to PowerShell, such as spaces to separate tokens);
    that is why `--install` *need not*, but *can* be quoted (PowerShell will simply remove the quotes for you before passing the argument to the target executable.)
  - ***expression mode***, which **works like expressions in *programming languages***.

PowerShell decides based on a statement's *first* token what parsing mode to apply:

**If the first token is a *quoted string*** - which we need here due to the embedded spaces in the executable path - **or a *variable reference* (e.g., `$var ...`), PowerShell parses in *expression mode* by default**.
A quoted string or a variable reference as an expression would simply *output* the string / variable value.

However, given that we want to *execute* the executable whose path is stored in a quoted string, we need **to force *argument mode*, which is what the `&` operator ensures**.

---

Generally, it's important to understand that **PowerShell performs nontrivial pre-processing of the command line** before the target executable is invoked, so what the command line looks like *in PowerShell code* is generally *not* directly what the *target executable* sees.

- If you reference a PowerShell *variable* on the command line and that **variable contains embedded spaces, PowerShell will implicitly enclose the variable's value in *double quotes*** before passing it on - this is discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22027051/45375) to the linked question.
- **PowerShell's *metacharacters* differ from that of `cmd.exe` and are more numerous** (notably, `,` has special meaning in PowerShell (array constructor), but not `cmd.exe` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41031197/45375)).
- **To simplify reuse of existing, `cmd.exe`-based command lines, PowerShell v3 introduced the special [*stop-parsing token*, `--%`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing#the-stop-parsing-token)**, which turns off PowerShell's normal parsing of the remainder of the command line and only interpolates `cmd.exe`-style environment-variable references (e.g., `%USERNAME%`). However, this comes with fundamental limitations - see the bottom section of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42601912/45375).