# Unable to edit with bcdedit filelds in powershell - cmd.exe command line fails

Tags: powershell, cmd, parameter-passing, bcdedit

Why can't I edit the description field using `bcdedit` in PowerShell?

For example, in `cmd.exe` the following command:

```
bcdedit /set {GUID} description "OS2"
```

completes successfully, changing the description field for the specified GUID, but when I do the same thing from Powershell, I get the following error:

```
The set command specified is not valid.
Run "bcdedit /?" for command line assistance.
The parameter is incorrect.
```

Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To **pass a value enclosed in `{...}` as a *literal* (as-is) in PowerShell, you must *quote* it**; e.g.:

```
bcdedit /set "{340E0E1A-01EC-4A33-A850-8D6A09FD4CE9}" description "OS2"
```

`{` and `}`, unlike in `cmd.exe`, are *metacharacters*, i.e., characters that have special meaning in PowerShell when used unquoted (they enclose a *script block*), which in this case happens to result in `{` and `}` simply getting *removed*.
Quoting prevents that.

**Alternatively**, you can **`` ` ``-escape the unquoted metacharacters *individually***:
`` bcdedit /set `{340E0E1A-01EC-4A33-A850-8D6A09FD4CE9`} description "OS2" ``

A **generic alternative, available since PSv3**, is to **use the so-called [*stop-parsing symbol*, `--%`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847892.aspx)**, which passes all remaining arguments as-is, without interpretation by PowerShell (with the exception of expanding `%...%`-enclosed environment-variable references):

```
bcdedit --% /set {340E0E1A-01EC-4A33-A850-8D6A09FD4CE9} description "OS2"
```

**Caveat**: While `--%` works as expected if all your arguments are *literals*, as in your case, **in general it prevents you from using *PowerShell variables* and *expressions* as / in arguments**, and can have other **unexpected side effects** - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42601912/45375).

---

#### Optional Background Information

Unless interpolation of PowerShell variables and expression is needed, **`--%` allows reuse of `cmd.exe` command lines as-is, without having to worry about PowerShell's quoting (escaping) requirements**.

Generally, **PowerShell's metacharacters** (characters that have special meaning when unquoted) **are different from `cmd.exe`'s and much more numerous**:

In *addition to* `cmd.exe`'s metachars.,

```
& | < >
```

PowerShell has:

```
( ) , { } ; @ $ #
```

<sup>`<`, `>`, `@` and `#` only have special meaning at the *start* of a token.

`<` is reserved for *future* use, as of PowerShell 7.0</sup>

Aside from that, with respect to **variable expansion (interpolation)**:

- **`cmd.exe`** only expands **`%...%`-enclosed** variable names (e.g., `%PATH%`), whereas **PowerShell requires `$`-prefixed** variable names (e.g., `$env:PATH` or `$HOME`) or `$(...)`-enclosed expressions (subexpression operator)

  - In both interpreters, variable expansion (and, in PowerShell, also subexpression expansion) is also performed inside `"..."` (double-quoted strings).
- `'...'` (single-quoted strings) are *literal* strings in PowerShell (contents is used as-is, without interpolation), whereas `'` has no special meaning to `cmd.exe` at all.

To **treat metacharacters as *literals***, you have two options:

- **Enclose them in *quoted strings***:

  - Both `cmd.exe` and PowerShell: enclose them in `"..."` (but potentially with interpolation of any variable references / subexpressions also enclosed in the string); e.g., `"|"`.
  - PowerShell only: enclose them in `'...'`; e.g., `'|'`
- **Escape them *individually***:

  - PowerShell: `` ` ``-escape them (backtick); e.g., `` `| ``

    - This also works inside `"..."`, although there it is only *needed* to escape `$` so as to prevent variable / subexpression expansion.
  - `cmd.exe`: `^`-escape them (caret); e.g., `^|`

    - This only works *outside* of `"..."`, and sadly, doesn't work for escaping `%` to suppress variable expansion - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31420292/45375) for the full story.

Comment: Thank you very much, for this thorough answer. It solved my problem, I will have to get some Powershell book to read more about this!! Cheers man

Comment: @MilosPeric: My pleasure; glad to hear it helped. Note that PowerShell also ships with conceptual help topics (although their depth and quality varies): `get-help about_*`; e.g., `get-help about_Parsing`. (Curiously, the `-online` switch for viewing the online version in a browser doesn't seem to work for conceptual topics, but googling the exact topic name works well).