# How to run this Beyond Compare script from Powershell?

Tags: powershell

currently I can use Beyond Compare script to output results to a file. You all were able to help me in figuring out how to check for differences in the result text file via Powershell. However, I do have another question. To get the results into a text file, Beyond Compare has you use a basic script and then run the script via cmd. My question is how do I run the script via Powershell instead of cmd? Below is the command used in cmd to run the script.

```
c:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 4>bcompare.exe @"C:\script.txt" "C:\test1" "C:\test" "C:\bcreport\report.txt"
```

The script that it is referencing is below.

```
load "%1" "%2"
expand all
folder-report layout:side-by-side options:display-mismatches output-to:"%3"
```

Thanks for any input. Getting this to work is all part of a much larger Powershell script I am working on. If I can get this to run from Powershell, it will save me a ton of time as I will be able to script something that takes hours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike in `cmd`, an unquoted `@` is a *metacharacter* in PowerShell; that is, it has special meaning<sup>[1]</sup>.

**To use `@` *verbatim***, in order to pass it through to `bcompare.exe` in this case, escape it with `` ` ``, which is PowerShell's escape character; i.e., **use `` `@ ``**:

```
bcompare.exe `@"C:\script.txt" "C:\test1" "C:\test" "C:\bcreport\report.txt"
```

**Alternatively**, *include* the `@` in the *quoted string*:

```
bcompare.exe "@C:\script.txt" "C:\test1" "C:\test" "C:\bcreport\report.txt"
```

Another alternative is to place **`--%`**, the so-called *stop-parsing symbol* before the arguments, as shown in [Wasif Hasan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60852407/45375); doing so prevents PowerShell from interpreting the arguments before passing them on.
However, note that while this works as expected if all your arguments are *literals*, as in your case, **in general it prevents you from using *PowerShell variables* and *expressions* as / in arguments**, and can have other **unexpected side effects** - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42601912/45375).

---

<sup>[1]</sup>

- `@` serves *multiple* syntactic purposes in PowerShell; with a `"` following the `@`, PowerShell thinks the argument is a [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules); since a here-string requires a multi-line definition, the command breaks due to a syntax error.  `@` before a *variable* name (e.g., `@foo`) performs [*splatting*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting)
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41031197/45375) contrasts `cmd`'s metacharacters with PowerShell's.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41254359/45375) has a comprehensive overview of how PowerShell parses unquoted command arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Or use `--%`, the [stop-parsing symbol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing), if you're using powershell v3+:

```
bcompare.exe --% @"C:\script.txt" "C:\test1" "C:\test" "C:\bcreport\report.txt"
```

Or use shown solution by @mklement0