# How to pass multiple arguments to dotCover merge

Tags: powershell, nunit, dotcover

I am writing powershell command to merge two snapshots as following -

```
&$coveragTool merge /Source= $TestResult1;$TestResult2 /Output= TestMergeOutput.dcvr
```

it is giving error as -

```
Parameter 'Source' has invalid value.
Invalid volume separator char ':' (0x3A) in path at index 67.
```

where as the document says two files should be separated by a semicolon(;)

like this -

```
merge: Merge several coverage snapshots
usage: dotCover merge|m <parameters>

Valid parameters:
  --Source=ARG             : (Required) List of snapshots separated with semicolon (;)
  --Output=ARG             : (Required) File name for the merged snapshot
  --TempDir=ARG            : (Optional) Directory for the auxiliary files. Set to system temp by default

Global parameters:
  --LogFile=ARG            : (Optional) Enables logging and allows specifying a log file name
  --UseEnvVarsInPaths=ARG  : (Optional) [True|False] Allows using environment variables (for example, %TEMP%) in paths. True
 by default
```

how do i make it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass an *unquoted* `;` as part of an argument, because PowerShell interprets it as a statement separator.

Either enclose the argument in `"..."`, or `` ` ``-escape the `;` character selectively; also, the space after `=` may or may not be a problem.

To make the call (at least syntactically) succeed, use the following:

```
& $coveragTool merge /Source="$TestResult1;$TestResult2" /Output=TestMergeOutput.dcvr
```

Alternatively (note the `` ` ``, ignore the broken syntax highlighting):

```
& $coveragTool merge /Source=$TestResult1`;$TestResult2 /Output=TestMergeOutput.dcvr
```

PowerShell has more so-called *metacharacters* than `cmd.exe`, for instance, notably `( ) , { } ; @ $ #` in addition to `& | < >` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41031197/45375) for additional information.