# Powershell invoke or execute (with & operator) a function with arguments?

Tags: powershell

I've got this ps snippet:

```
function myFuncWithArgs($arg) { 
    Write-Output $arg 
}

$temp = 'sometext'

$cFunc = 'myFuncWithArgs' 
& $cFunc $temp
```

it works but I need the $temp to be on the same line as $cFunc and work the same. This does not work:

```
$cFunc = 'myFuncWithArgs' $temp
& $cFunc
```

is this possible in pshell?

Comment: What should `$cFunc` be because what you have right now is a syntax error. Should it be a string or an array?

Comment: Not sure I really understand what you are doing but maybe try to remove the quotes. $cFunc = myFuncWithArgs $temp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to store a *complete command* (executable + arguments) in a variable for *later execution on demand*.

Use a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) for that, which you can call on demand with `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-):

```bash
# Define the full command as a script block.
$scriptBlock = { myFuncWithArgs $temp }

# Invoke it.
# You may also pass arguments to it, but that only makes sense
# if it is designed to accept them, e.g. via $args
& $scriptBlock
```

Note:

- `&` does *not* work with a *string* containing a complete command.  Its argument must either be a script block, as shown, or command name or executable path, and any arguments to pass to that script block / command / executable must be specified *separately*, e.g.
  `& { Write-Output $args } arg1 ...` or `& $pathToExecutable arg1 ...`
- Read on for how execute a complete command stored in a string, which can be a *security risk*, however.

---

The above uses a script-block *literal*.
To create a script block from a *string*, use [`[scriptblock]::Create()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.Create):

```bash
# IMPORTANT: 
#  Be sure that you either fully control or implicitly trust
#  the content of this string, so as to prevent execution of unwanted code.
$commandString = 'myFuncWithArgs $temp'

$scriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create($commandString)

& $scriptBlock
```

You mention [`Read-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host), i.e. prompting the user, as the source of your command string, in which case the caveat under "IMPORTANT:" above definitely applies.

- *If* the risk of execution arbitrary user-supplied commands is acceptable to you, you could simply use [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression) `$commandString` - but note that `Invoke-Expression` is [generally discouraged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/avoid-using-invoke-expression) precisely for its ability to execute arbitrary code stored in a string.
- However, there is middle ground, which *does* require `[scriptblock]::Create()`:

  - Before invoking the script block, you can call its [`.CheckRestrictedLanguage()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.CheckRestrictedLanguage) method to ensure that the resulting command only contains commands permitted in `Restricted` [language mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Language_Modes), with configurability as to which specific commands and variables are permitted.

Comment: this works: `$scriptBlock = {myFuncWithArgs 'some text'}
& $scriptBlock` but if I try to use Read-Host -prompt and paste into the console `{myFuncWithArgs 'some text'}` then I get an error: `& : The term '{myFuncWithArgs 'some text'}' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program.`

Comment: I'm using Read-Host to listen to data from a parent NodeJS script,. The NodeJS  script works fine with single functions: `spawnedChild.stdin.write("functionNOArgs\r");` , but I still can't get it to work with args: `spawnedChild.stdin.write("functionWithArgs\r  'R:/file.txt'");` . I should've started the thread including this info but I reckoned that I was just messing up the syntax or some other minor issue.

Comment: finally,  it's working! When writing a function and arg, there is no need for \r after the function, so: `spawnedChild.stdin.write("functionWithArgs 'R:/file.txt'");` with `[scriptblock]::Create` = solution, thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @bitbar. Indeed, `\r` shouldn't be used, because PowerShell expects a given commands to either be on a single line or use explicit line continuation with `\`` (the exception is when a command is _syntactically incomplete_, in which case PowerShell looks at the next line too, such as when placing a `|` at the end of a line).

Answer (score 2):

You can assign to multiple variables at once, thus keeping things on the same line:

```
$cFunc,$cArgs = 'myFuncWithArgs',$temp
& $cFunc @cArgs
```