# How to convert a string that currently has a switch parameter into a function in powershell

Tags: string, powershell, function, parameters, switch-statement

I have a string like this:

"CleanUp -All"

How do you convert it into a callable function in PowerShell including the switch?

I tried calling "&" in front of the entire string.

I tried splitting up the string into parts and calling them together.

I used the "&" to call the first part of the string "CleanUp" into a function but I don't know how to convert the switch parameter to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- A string containing a *command line* - i.e. a command name/path *plus arguments* - can *not* be invoked with `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-) - `&` only operates solely on a *command name/path*, requiring any arguments to be passed *separately* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38066651/45375).
- While you *can* use [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression) to execute a string containing an entire command line:

  - Use of `Invoke-Expression` (`iex`) is [best avoided](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/avoid-using-invoke-expression) in general.
  - Such an invocation (`iex 'CleanUp -All'`) does *not* act like a *function* in two respects:

    - It requires *renewed parsing* of the command line in *repeat* invocations.
    - It doesn't accept *additional arguments* - unless you use string interpolation to make them part of the string passed to `iex`.
- The better solution is to create a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks), which is only parsed *once* and can be re-invoked on demand with `&` (or, if the intent is to directly execute in the caller's scope, with `.`, the [dot-sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-)):

  ```bash
  # Create a script block from the command-line string, which you can
  # invoke on demand with & or . - e.g.: & $sb
  $sb = [scriptblock]::Create('CleanUp -All')
  ```

  - If you additionally want to support *pass-through* arguments, append  `@args` to the command-line string:

    ```bash
    $sb = [scriptblock]::Create('CleanUp -All' + ' @args')
    ```
  - If you want to create an actual, named *function*, `Invoke-Expression` is the simplest solution, after all:

    ```bash
    # Define function 'Foo' which calls CleanUp -All with pass-through
    # arguments, if any.
    iex ('function Foo { ' + 'CleanUp -All' + ' @args }')
    ```

Answer (score 0):

Through a pipe:

```
"CleanUp -All" | iex
```

As an argument:

```
iex -Command "CleanUp -All"
```

As a function:

```
function myfunc {
  CleanUp -All
}
```